# Having issues getting custom marker icon to load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can not get my custom marker to load. I have looked around and all the sites say about the same thing but i can not get it to load!

I am using an iPage web hosting subscription, and have uploaded the image to the file manager(looks to be where all the CSS/HTML, images, etc are uploaded and kept). Here is my code for the map options:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_container"),myOptions);
    var iconImage = '/horseriding.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng, 
      map: map,
      icon: iconImage,
      title:"Farm Entrance"
    });
```

Is this an issue of the call not knowing where the image is located(file path incorrect?)? or is this a syntax issue?

Comment: you wrote: "Is this an issue of the call not knowing where the image is located (file path incorrect)?" If you remove the icon definition from the Marker constructor, do you get the default icon? Is your icon at the root of your webserver and can you load it from that path in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

After i saw your code, the only error i see is this

`var iconImage = '/horseriding.png';`

i think your horseriding is inside the `img folder` so it should be `image/horseriding.png` or `img/horseriding.png`

of if it is in your root folder it should be `var iconImage= 'horseriding.png';`

Comment: I tried both ways and it still doesn't work. if i open the image by itself in the browser it goes to "www.TheWebSiteI'mMaking.com/horseriding.png". so theoretically your recommendation of 'var iconImage= 'horseriding.png';' should work then correct? thank you for your reply!

Comment: by the way, what is the size of horseriding? if your using only icon attribute of marker, the image will crop into 64x64 or 32x32 (not sure).

Comment: its only a 32x37 image...i found a map icon off the web so it shouldn't have issues there.